# How to prove that a spline is a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, spline, numerical-calculus

Let $\Delta$ be a subdivision of $[a,b]$:

$a=t_1 < t_2 <\ldots < t_N =b$. Then

$\mathbb{S}_{m}^{k}(\Delta )=\{s\in \mathcal{C}^{k}([a,b]) : s_{\mid_{[t_i , t_{i+1}]}}\in\mathbb{P}_{m}, i=1,\ldots ,N-1\}$

where $\mathbb{P}_{m}$ is the linear space of Polynomials of degree $≤m$.

Prove that $\mathbb{S}_{m}^{m}(\Delta )=\mathbb{P}_m$

Obviously, $\mathbb{P}_m\subseteq\mathbb{S}_{m}^{m}(\Delta )$ but in the other case I have no idea. The problem in the splines are the points $t_i$ but in this case we don't have any problems of differentiability but I don't know what let me see that $s$ is a polynomial. Can someone give me an advice? Thanks before!

Comment: For the spline to be $m$-times differentiable at a node $t_i$, $s\vert_{[t_{i-1},t_i]}$ and $s\vert_{[t_i,t_{i+1}]}$ must have the same derivatives up to order $m$ at $t_i$. What can you say about two degree $\le m$ polynomials whose derivatives up to order $m$ at a point agree?

Comment: Maybe they're the same because of Taylor formula?